# Add mouse event in pdf

Tags: javascript, pdf

I want to add Text to speech facility in pdf inside iframe of html page. I want to add mouseevent in the pdf so that when text in pdf is selected that text is assigned to a variable and is spoken out. Is there any mouseevent or  way to detect selected text in pdf?